# How to limit the access to a folder

Tags: .htaccess, ip

I could find that to limit the access to a folder I can put that in the .htaccess

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <your ip>
```

or this:

```
<RequireAll>
    Require ip xx.xx.xx.xx yy.yy.yy.yy
</RequireAll>
```

But I do not have a static ip. Is there any way I can limit the access to a folder if my ip is dynamic?

(Why I need this? I have a folder in the ftp that I want to use it to test things. In robots.txt I tell Google not to follow that folder. I have already done this. Some people recommend to limit the access to that folder, also.)

Comment: How about password-protecting the folder?  See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by creating a robots.txt in your root directory and adding the following lines in it:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /directory
Disallow: /filename.extension
```

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain well. I have already done this. My question is not how to say Google to not follow the folder. My question is how to limit the access to that folder.